# why do I get these weird artifacts on my mesh?

Tags: modeling, shaders, normals, topology, artifacts

[image: the table top has some shading issues]

is it some shading issue, I recalculated the normals. is there anything else I should do?

Comment: Looks like there is another table (geometry) on top of it.

Comment: Agreed - it's got that distinctive z-fighting "fuzz".

Comment: Brockmann thank you that fixed it.  and what's that "fuzz" mean Christopher.